# How can I select columns by a range of date in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tk2Kv.png)

I select columns by a range of date :

```
date1 = datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 31)
date2 = datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 31)

df[date1 : date2]
```

But found error on the slicing index:

```
cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [2018-12-31 00:00:00] of <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Question:
How can I slice columns by a range of date ?

Comment: look this 
https://www.pythonprogramming.in/get-range-of-dates-between-specified-start-and-end-date.html

Comment: I read your link. Just exactly not in what I mean. I am not going to set the column as my index column. I want to select multiple column but not by explicitly typing all the date, say I want all column in December, I just want it to select from start date then to the end date automatically.

Comment: @jezrael please review.

Comment: I am not making a column become a index please. My only date format data are on the column header, the data on every row is number. I know what you mean now. Apologies My df is confusing. Please have a look on new one https://ibb.co/jvfCsqp @jezrael

Comment: do you need `df.loc[:, date1 : date2]` ?

Comment: yes exactly. I dont know why it is not working

Comment: oh my bad. df.loc[:, date1 : date2] is working but not  df.[ date1 : date2]. Why it that ?